# Wordpress Permalinks on IIS 7 with WCF services using service factory

Tags: wordpress, wcf, iis, permalinks

Suppose you're hosting Wordpress on IIS 7 and you want to activate permalinks.  Looking at the codex [here](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/enabling-pretty-permalinks-in-wordpress), you'll see this example code for the web.config file (located at the root of your WordPress install) to be added in the `<system.webServer>` tag:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

All is well and the url rewrite rule's conditions correctly ignore existing files and folders present on the system.

However, you may come to a situtation, as I did, where you need to ignore every uri that lies within a certain sub folder, even if there is not a corresponding file on the filesystem.  In my case I am hosting a set of WCF services in a subdirectory `/Services/` using the `<serviceActivations>` area of the web.config (at the subdirectory) in the form:

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
   <serviceActivations>
     <add factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory" relativeAddress="./AccountService.svc" service="MyAssembly.Services.AccountService"/>
  </serviceActivations>
</serviceHostingEnvironment>
```

Navigating to the `AccountService.svc` will cause a 404 not found.

How can you handle this situation?  Below I have posted my specific solution, but there are other ways to achieve this.  Also, a general case solution is still elusive, so the question remains, how can you handle this situation generally?

Answer (score 0):

Below I've provided my solution as a complete newbie to the world of URL Rewrite.  The solution is specific to a particular folder.

To solve my problem is was necessary to add an additional condition to the rewrite rules:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/Services/.*" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

In your case, substituting your folder name where I have "Services" will suffice.

What if you wanted to do this for any directory or directory hierarchy, such that if the directory hierarchy exists, then let any url containing that directory hierarchy pass through without being rewritten.  My attempt at this has thus far centered around matching the portion of the url which contains the directory hierarchy and using a back reference to detect if this directory exists:

```
        <rule name="ignoreSubDirectoryURIs" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)/.*\..*" ignoreCase="false" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH}\{R:1}\" matchType="IsDirectory" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="None" />
        </rule>
```

This rule is added first so that if it is successful the other rewrite rule is not interpreted.

Problems:  while `{APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH}` is a directory, I haven't been able to get any combination of `{APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH}` and a sub directory to resolve correctly.  The other problem is with nested directories, where the `{R:1}` will return dir1/dir2, instead of dir1\dir2, which may make this not work for the nested case.

Reading the [URL Rewrite Reference](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference) has been instructive if not complete